# Reading aliases as strings in ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I have a YAML file that contains strings with wildcards, for example:

```
hello : world
foo : *
bar : ruamel.*
```

This fails when passed on to `ruamel.yaml.load` because the `*` asterisk, if the first character of a keyword (string), indicates the beginning of an alias. If it's somewhere in between as for the value of `bar` in this example, it works.

Since it's not so nice to write and read if all the`*`-led strings have to be protected with quotation marks and I don't need the anchor/alias support in my file anyway, I thought I'd disable it in the Loader somehow. I didn't find an option in the `ruamel.yaml.Loader` directly, so I looked around the code a bit and came up with the following:

```py
from ruamel import yaml

class NoAliasLoader(yaml.Loader):
    def fetch_alias(self):                        
        return self.fetch_plain()

yaml.load(yml_doc, Loader=NoAliasLoader)
```

This works and the value is interpreted as a string as intended, but only if another character follows the `*`, like in `foo : **`. If it's only the asterisk, there's an error saying

```py
ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:yaml'
  in "<unicode string>", line 3, column 7:
    foo : *
          ^ (line: 3)
```

I didn't find an easy solution to that just from going through the code and had to give up.

So how can I achieve what I want? Or is there an option in the `Loader` somewhere that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps involved in parsing YAML using `ruamel.yaml` are in the order of applying the
result from the one to the other:

```
YAML document → scanning → parsing → composing → constructing → Python data structure
```

When you pass your document to `YAML().load()`, you get a `ScannerError`, so trying to "fix" that 
in the construction phase is way to late.

---

The actual check on '*' at the start of a token is done in the method `fetch_more_tokens` in
`scanner.py` and you could of course change that method (either by subclassing or monkey-patching),
but it is over one hunderd lines, most of which you would have to copy verbatim.

The relevant part is:

```
    # Is it an alias?
    if ch == '*':
        return self.fetch_alias()
```

And it is much simpler to just replace `.fetch_alias()` with the routine to
fetch a "normal" plain scalar (`.fetch_plain()`):

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
hello : world
foo : *
bar : ruamel.*
"""

ruamel.yaml.scanner.Scanner.fetch_alias = ruamel.yaml.scanner.Scanner.fetch_plain
ruamel.yaml.resolver.implicit_resolvers = ruamel.yaml.resolver.implicit_resolvers[:-1]

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe', pure=True)

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
for k in data:
    print('{:6s} -> {:10s} [{}]'.format(k, data[k], type(data[k])))
```

which gives:

```
hello  -> world      [<class 'str'>]
foo    -> *          [<class 'str'>]
bar    -> ruamel.*   [<class 'str'>]
```

Comment: Hi Anthon. But replacing `fetch_alias` with `fetch_plain` is exactly what I tried and describend in my OP (although with suclassing instead of monkeypatchig), but which didn't work for me. At least not for single `*` strings. And the error is a `ConstructorError`, not a `ScannerError`.

Comment: Sorry I had not read the details of your OP correctly. The old style (PyYAML) API works differently, you would  probably need to subclass the Scanner instance, then create a new Loader class from that subclasses and the normal classes, much like the boilerplate stuff you find in `loader.py`. The `ScannerError` I refer to is from loading the document in the original, I have not investigated why you get the `ConstructorError`, I went straight for a working alternative (not wanting to waste time on the old API).

Comment: Using the `YAML().load()` approach indeed makes a difference and the error goes away. Although looking at the returned object, it now became a `CommentedMap` and it contains a `<ruamel.yaml.comments.TaggedScalar ..>` object where the `*` originally was. So still not quite what I wanted, at least without further post-processing.

Comment: I updated the answer, to use `typ='safe'`. You have to specify `pure=True`, as otherwise you would be using the C based parser, and you cannot just reassign `fetch_alias` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I finallly also figured out how to achieve that with PyYAML directly. Additionally to monkey patching `fetch_alias` into `fetch_plain`, it's required to remove the `*` key from the `yaml_implicit_resolvers` dict. That's what caused the mentioned `ConstructorError`.

```py
import yaml
yaml.Loader.fetch_alias = yaml.Loader.fetch_plain
yaml.Loader.yaml_implicit_resolvers.pop("*", None)
```

As a result:

```py
yaml.load("""
hello : world
foo : *
bar : 10
""")
>>> {'bar': 10, 'foo': '*', 'hello': 'world'}
```